# Deleting item in one component causes app to break and throw undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, undefined

Im using react and am working with redux to delete an item. The item deletes, however, right after deleting the item, the app crashes and gives an undefined error. Its happening in components that are not related to what I am trying to do.

[image]

Just my guess is that when I delete an item, other components that use that item gets undefined since its no longer populating data/info from that element. Im not sure how to handle this as I have tried several options including the below that I have found during my research which is adding the '?' right before '.type' but the app crashes after doing that, saying its wrong syntax(unexpected symbol):

```
const { currentAccountId, accounts } = props;
const currentAccountType = currentAccountId ? accounts.filter(acc => acc.id === currentAccountId)[0]?.type : null;
```

If any other method as to overcome the type error, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
const { currentAccountId, accounts } = props;
const currentAccountType = null;
if(currentAccountId) {
 let currentAccount = accounts.filter(acc => acc.id === currentAccountId)[0];
 if(currentAccount) currentAccountType = currentAccount.type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just after doing that, I get another exception error elsewhere. Not sure how to implement that in the same way in this code:


Cannot read property 'assets' of undefined


  filterViewBalances() {
    const { holdingsByAccount, holdingsByAsset, currentAccountId } = this.props;
    if (currentAccountId) {
      return holdingsByAccount.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId).assets;
    }
    return holdingsByAsset;
  }

Comment: Try this-
filterViewBalances() { 
  const { holdingsByAccount, holdingsByAsset, currentAccountId } = this.props; 
if (currentAccountId) { 
return holdingsByAccount.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId)?.assets; 
} 
return holdingsByAsset; 
}